# How I can allow traffic to my domain across VPC and do this inaccessible when the user is outside the VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

Right now I have the next resource relation:

S3 -> Route 53 (domain) -> Internet

But I just want this domain available under VPC. And not for the rest of the internet. The VPC just is accessible across a corporate VPN (Direct Connect)!

S3 -> Route 53 (domain) -> VPC -> Direct Connect -> VPN

I am really don't know if this approach is correct or if I need some additional services.

Comment: You could potentially setup [private hosted zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) in R53.

Answer (score 0):

Route53 provides option to create internal zone files for internal domains, that will be accessible within your VPCs.
While creating a hosted zone in Route53 you can choose **Create Private Hosted Zone**

You can follow the offical doc here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-private-creating.html

And when you are connecting your office network these domains will be accessible